Listen to global keyboard and mouse events Tauri app(Mac os)
`In a tauri app(MacOS primarily) want to listen global keypress and mouse events.
I tried using rdev(https://github.com/Narsil/rdev.git) and here's the code but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing is printed in terminal.
Code is like:
use rdev::{listen, Event}; use std::thread; use tauri::Manager;

fn callback(event: Event) { println!("My callback {:?}", event); } fn main() { thread::spawn(|| listen(callback));
tauri::Builder::default()
    .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![
    ])
    .setup(|app| {
        let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();
        window.open_devtools();
        Ok(())
    })
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("error while running Tauri application");
}


Did you see the macos section in rdev's readme? https://github.com/Narsil/rdev#macos

Yes. And I also added in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility.

You may want to put your entire logic in the tauri::Builder scope.
I believe the listen function is never called in the first place. Or does not have enough rights to run or is simply not on the same runtime as your tauri app . trying using a eprintln before the listen function is called to make sure it was even called in the first place.
And review the os link caveats for rdev
